# Docker Compose - /bin/sh: jest: not found

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, jestjs

I have an express app with a Dockerfile. I'm trying to set up Docker Compose but encountered an error below running target either `dev` or `test`. Seems to be that Docker Compose is not installing the `devDependencies` that's why it couldn't find the packages needed like `jest` or `concurrently`. See error below:

```
web    | yarn run v1.22.5
web    | $ jest --runInBand --detectOpenHandles --forceExit
web    | /bin/sh: jest: not found
web    | error Command failed with exit code 127.
web    | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
web exited with code 127
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as base

WORKDIR /app

COPY [ "package.json", "yarn.lock*", "./" ]

FROM base as dev
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
CMD [ "yarn", "dev" ]

FROM dev as test
CMD [ "yarn", "test" ]

FROM dev as test-watch
ENV GIT_WORK_TREE=/app GIT_DIR=/app/.git
RUN apk add git
CMD [ "yarn", "test:watch" ]

FROM base as prod
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production
COPY . .
RUN yarn build
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    image: node:16-alpine
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - PORT=5000
```

And my `test.yml` file:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      target: test
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=test
```

Then here's my command when trying to run via Docker Compose:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f test.yml up --build
```

Do note that it runs perfectly fine with just Docker or in my local. Not sure where the problem lies. Hope anyone could help. It will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The `volumes:` are hiding absolutely everything in the image: whatever's in your host's `./node_modules` directory is replacing the image's `/app/node_modules`, and it doesn't matter whether you install production or non-production dependencies on different paths in the image build since the host directory will take precedence.  Does removing the `volumes:` help?  Can you run the unit tests on your host system before involving Docker?

Comment: You are right, removing it worked for me, interesting to know more about volumes. Just a question if you don't mind. How come when I run my test with mongodb, a folder `db` gets created in my root folder? I have this volumes config in my mongodb `- ./db:/data/db` so based on what you said, it should be the other way around right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, `volumes` in my `docker-compose.yml` should be:

```
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
```

As [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze), pointed out. Previous config `./:/app` was hiding absolutely everything in the image: whatever's in my host's `./node_modules` directory is replacing the image's `/app/node_modules`, and it doesn't matter whether I install production or non-production dependencies on different paths in the image build since the host directory will take precedence.